# Create and use table referencing two rows of one other table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

A tale of three tables: using Entity Framework 6, I need a user-editable table Disallow to store conflicts between rows of another table Option of type Technology.

Like this:

```
Technology:
ID, PK, [int], not null
Description, nvarchar(40), not null

Option:
ID, PK, [int], not null
Name, nvarchar(20), not null
ADD CONSTRAINT (FK_Tech) FOREIGN KEY [ID] REFERENCES [Technology] (ID)

Disallow:
ID1, [int], not null
ID2, [int], not null
PRIMARY KEY (ID1, ID2) ASC
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Valid1] FOREIGN KEY [ID1] REFERENCES [Option] (ID)
ADD CONSTRAING (FK_Valid2) FOREIGN KEY [ID2] REFERENCES [Option] (ID)
```

As I understand it, after importing the database into the model the user should be able to add records from the EF model so that e can specify that when choosing technology options, it should be disallowed to choose two particular options together.

I have spent much time looking for help on using multiple foreign keys into a single table and was able to create the table successfully in SQL Server and I think I understand the issues there.

But when I attempt to import into EF, an association is shown, on the Options table, but nothing else.  How can I add rows if there is no mapping to the table?  And then I found a link telling me that there is no way to reference a foreign key.  So I added two additional fields, but even after numerous attempts -- following the advice of many links on THAT topic -- failed to bring the table into the model.  How can I ensure (1) that the IDs added to the Disallow table are found in Option, and (2) still reference them in EF?

Or perhaps better said, how can I accomplish what I want: rows of conflicts that my code will use to limit the selection of options?

Comment: I don't have an answer, because I've never had a problem doing this.  Can you add screenshots of the EF designer, maybe?   Also, a conceptual question: Is `Disallow(5, 27)` different from `Disallow(27,5)`?  If not, have you considered how are you going to ensure that the choice is correctly blocked in both directions?

Comment: I will add a screenshot when I can.  Yes, I have considered that 5,27 and 27,5 differ but should produce the same result and plan to add a record for both directions.  Let me ask: when yours worked, did you get a table, or were you able to just use the association?  Note that I am using DB-first.

Comment: Ah, yes, Entity Framework...  I've seen this before, years ago with EF4.1.  The last thing I did last night was try to update the model from the database and it failed.  I posted this question and went home.  This morning it works.  What refreshes every so often to make EF work?  Anyone know?

Comment: No idea about the general case - timeouts, maybe?  I ran into a problem myself this morning because I was still pointed at the old database server *just* for the EF schema, and hadn't noticed.  All the code had been updated with the new connection strings, but not the designer.